# How do I limit the area a movieclip can be dragged?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, flash-cs6

I am making a interactive map in as3/flash cs6.
At the moment, I've got it to zoom in and out, and be dragged around.

But my question is, how to I limit the area the map can be dragged, so it you can't see the white space outside of it?

Here is my code:

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    function initDragger(mc:MovieClip):void
    {
        mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
        mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);


    }

    function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.startDrag();

    }
    function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

    }

    // Set up drag
    initDragger(map);

    zoomIn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mapzoomin);

    function mapzoomin(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (map.scaleX < 10)
        {
            map.scaleX +=  1;
            map.scaleY +=  1;
        }

    }

    zoomOut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mapzoomout);

    function mapzoomout(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (map.scaleX > 1)
        {
            map.scaleX -=  1;
            map.scaleY -=  1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: startDrag can accept rectangle(bound) where you can drag item. Take a look at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29

Comment: Alright, I see. So do I just make the bounds the same as my map?

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle dimensions should be in relation to the upper left corner of your draggable item. So if you had a 100x100 map and a 50x50 viewable area, the rectangle would be {x:-50, y:-50, width: 50, height:50}

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way of doing this would be to check what the x and y coordiantes of the map are and making sure they don't go further than you want. 
eg. 
(pretend your stage is 200px wide and high)

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function update(e:Event)
{
    if(map.x > 0) map.x = 0;
    if(map.x < map.width - 200) map.x = map.width - 200;
    if(map.y > 0) map.y = 0;
    if(map.y < 0 - (map.height - 200)) map.y = 0 - (map.height - 200);
}
```

I haven't tested that, but it should be right.